# Cloudfoundry : No matching distribution found for python==3.5.0

Tags: ibm-cloud, python-3.5, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy a python application on IBM Bluemix cloud via clodfoundry. The buildpack compilation fails. logs

`2016-04-08T09:23:04.732-0400[API/1]OUTUpdated app with guid 4823889e-5491-40a3-a8ce-35b8dd325441 ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
2016-04-08T09:23:07.713-0400[DEA/4]OUTGot staging request for app with id 4823889e-5491-40a3-a8ce-35b8dd325441
2016-04-08T09:23:11.178-0400[API/0]OUTUpdated app with guid 4823889e-5491-40a3-a8ce-35b8dd325441 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
2016-04-08T09:23:11.376-0400[STG/4]OUT-----> Downloaded app package (72K)
2016-04-08T09:23:12.762-0400[STG/4]OUT-----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (29M)
2016-04-08T09:23:12.901-0400[STG/0]ERRCloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/buildpack-python'...
2016-04-08T09:23:14.625-0400[STG/0]OUTSubmodule 'compile-extensions' (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/compile-extensions.git) registered for path 'compile-extensions'
2016-04-08T09:23:14.679-0400[STG/0]ERRCloning into 'compile-extensions'...
2016-04-08T09:23:15.534-0400[STG/0]OUTSubmodule path 'compile-extensions': checked out '9932bb1d352b88883d76df41e797a6fa556844f0'
2016-04-08T09:23:15.782-0400[STG/0]OUT-------> Buildpack version 1.5.5
2016-04-08T09:23:16.785-0400[STG/0]OUT-----> Found python-2.7.10, removing
2016-04-08T09:23:17.035-0400[STG/0]OUT-----> Installing python-3.5.0
2016-04-08T09:23:21.330-0400[STG/0]OUTDownloaded [https://pivotal-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/concourse-binaries/python/python-3.5.0-linux-x64.tgz]
2016-04-08T09:23:27.161-0400[STG/0]OUT ! Please remove to ensure expected behavior.
2016-04-08T09:23:27.161-0400[STG/0]OUT ! The package setuptools/distribute is listed in requirements.txt.
2016-04-08T09:23:29.058-0400[STG/0]OUT $ pip install -r requirements.txt
2016-04-08T09:23:29.728-0400[STG/0]ERRDEPRECATION: --allow-all-external has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Due to changes in the repository protocol, it no longer has any effect.
2016-04-08T09:23:29.757-0400[STG/0]OUT Collecting django==1.9.5 (from -r mysite/requirements.txt (line 1))
2016-04-08T09:23:30.078-0400[STG/0]OUT Downloading Django-1.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6MB)
2016-04-08T09:23:32.696-0400[STG/0]OUT Collecting docopt==0.6.2 (from -r mysite/requirements.txt (line 2))
2016-04-08T09:23:32.758-0400[STG/0]OUT Downloading docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz
2016-04-08T09:23:33.446-0400[STG/0]OUT Collecting elasticsearch==2.3.0 (from -r mysite/requirements.txt (line 3))
2016-04-08T09:23:33.525-0400[STG/0]OUT Downloading elasticsearch-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (51kB)
2016-04-08T09:23:33.552-0400[STG/0]OUT Collecting hdfs==2.0.5 (from -r mysite/requirements.txt (line 4))
2016-04-08T09:23:33.631-0400[STG/0]OUT Downloading hdfs-2.0.5.tar.gz
2016-04-08T09:23:34.330-0400[STG/0]OUT Collecting python==3.5.0 (from -r mysite/requirements.txt (line 6))
2016-04-08T09:23:34.364-0400[STG/0]ERR Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python==3.5.0 (from -r mysite/requirements.txt (line 6)) (from versions: )
2016-04-08T09:23:34.962-0400[STG/0]ERRNo matching distribution found for python==3.5.0 (from -r mysite/requirements.txt (line 6))
2016-04-08T09:23:35.249-0400[STG/0]OUTStaging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
2016-04-08T09:23:35.468-0400[API/0]ERRencountered error: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase`

my requirements

django==1.9.5
docopt==0.6.2
elasticsearch==2.3.0
hdfs==2.0.5
pip==8.1.1
python==3.5.0
requests==2.9.1
setuptools==20.3
simplejson==3.8.2
six==1.10.0
urllib3==1.14
vs2015_runtime==14.00.23026.0
wheel==0.29.0

the command i ran

`cf push pytest -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/buildpack-python.git`

how should i deploy this?

**Edit**

i changed python version to 2.7.10 and removed the `vs2015-runtime==14.00.23026.0` requirement. Now i get

```
$ python mysite/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "mysite/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/manag
ement/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/manag
ement/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
           self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/manag
ement/__init__.py", line 190, in fetch_command
           klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/manag
ement/__init__.py", line 41, in load_command_class
           return module.Command()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/st
aticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 32, in __init__
           self.storage.path('')
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/st
aticfiles/storage.py", line 48, in path
           raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
       django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles
 app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
 !     Error while running '$ python mysite/manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
```

and here is what my project setup looks like

[image]

and in my settings.py i have

```
STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

what am i doing wrong?

**Update**

thanks a lot Hobert Bush for your help. i did as you suggested and now i'm almost there. The problem is that  now django cant find some of my static files. I have a piece of code like

```
hdfsProps = ReadProp.load_properties("hdfsStats/props/hdfsprops.prop")
```

and here is the layout

[image]

so i want to read those two prop files. note that this works perfectly in my local pc. even if i dont create the `hdfsStas/props/` structure inside 'static'

how should i change my layout so that my code can pick up these files? i even tried `../../props/hdfsprops.prop` but that gives me the same error. Lastly, the code that reads in the files is inside the `src` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please revert to Python runtime 2.7.10, as this is the highest runtime level currently supported using the Bluemix Python Buildpack.

Comment: thanks, i changed it to 2.7.10 but now i get `No matching distribution found for vs2015-runtime==14.00.23026.0`

Comment: @AbtPst I understand, can you provide the output of cf logs --recent?

Comment: @AbtPst Thank you for adding the logs. Try:
```STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')```

I removed the "/"

Comment: by the way, i found a way to get it to work with python 3.5.1
all we have to do is remove the `python==3.5.1` from the requirements file. it is enough to mention that in the runtime. Then the cf push works like a charm :)

Comment: @AbtPst Thanks for letting me know and following up. I'll edit my answer to include that as well